# Is there specific reason for naming PWM channels as LEDC in Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

Out of curiosity, why the PWM channels in ARDUINO  are named LEDC ?

Comment: Pure guess without knowing much about arduino: the pin is multi-purpose depending on configuration, so it has to have some name?

Comment: Possibly (just a guess as well) because you can dim an LED with a PWM, just reduce the duty cycle. If frequency is high enough, human eye won't notice the flickering, solely the LED getting darker. Maybe it's what they assumed people would do most often with PWM...

Comment: they are not. where did you see it?

Comment: `ledc` is probably short for `ledChannel`: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-pwm-arduino-ide/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ESP32 is not an Arduino, and it does not make sense to emulate Arduino's `analogWrite` completely for an ESP32, when adding support for ESP32 PWM to the Arduino IDE. (Besides the fact that *analog*Write` is a misleading name anyway)

**Why**-questions are always complicated (I know by my granddaughter) so additionally to

- Why did *they* call it "ledcXyz"

I'd rather add

- Why is there the "sigmaDelta" Extension as well

if we talk about the [espressif Arduino Extension](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32)

Comment: You nailed it, yes I slipped to mention about ESP32 extension of Arduino.. anyway I find it rather annoying to call everything that has to do with PWM as LED ...